# gdb break in dynamic library

Tags: python, c, dll, gdb

I am trying to use ctypes to access a dynamic library in python.
So far, I have created a bunch of structures in python to reflect the structure types in the library.  I am now trying to test these structures to see if I have translated everything correctly.  I currently have something like the following set up

```
import ctypes as ct

class MyStruct(ct.Structure)
    ''' put the actual implementation here '''
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mylib = ct.CDLL('/path/to/mylib.dylib')

    loadFile = mylib.loadFile

    loadFile.restype = ct.Pointer(MyStruct)

    parent = MyStruct()

    file = b"/path/to/file"

    child = loadFile(file, ct.byref(parent))

    print(child)
```

Now, for some reason this segfaults inside the dynamic library when I try to run this code.  I am trying to determine where (and why) this happens. I have compiled both the library and my python executable with debug info and am now trying to use gdb to locate the problem.  I can start my program and break at a line inside loadFile very nicely

```
gdb b loading.c:172
gdb r
```

and gdb breaks.  Now, there is another function call (this function is also part of the dynamic library) on line 172 in loading.c that I want to step into.  I tried to break inside this other function

```
gdb b foo.c:636
```

but gdb keeps giving me

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x2860
```

errors.  Further, if I just break at line 172 and then use `stepi` then I can't get any debug info.  Is there a way to get into this other function or is it a limitation of gdb when using dynamic libraries.

Comment: What have you allocated for the struct (in python)?  You must allocate memory for the struct itself.

Comment: @cdarke I have completely filled out the structs in python with various base ctypes types.  I'm sure that there is probably a typo in an element name or type somewhere that is causing the segfault (I translated over 2500 lines of c structures into python ctypes structures), but it would be much easier to discover which element(s) is(are) causing the problem(s) if I could see where the segfault is actually happening, thus my question about gdb.

Comment: Did you try `bt` command (backtrace)?